# How to install Ruby and ROR using vagrant/virtualbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, vagrant

I finally caved after working for a week to try and install ruby. I'm new to the language and using vagrant and virtual box ubuntu/trusty64 to install everything using boostrap.sh and vagrant file. It did not download the right version of ruby or rails despite my provisions. I tried to do [ruby -v] & [rails -v] in terminal and here's what I got.

I ran [vagrant up, and [vagrant ssh], then [ruby -v] [rails -v]

the result:
[image]

I am also attaching my boostrap.sh AND vagrantfile incase that helps.

```
#BOOTSTRAP.SH

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# upgrade and update the system
echo upgrading and updating the system
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
# install node.js for js runtime when using Rails
echo installing nodejs for ExecJS runtime and git
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install -y git
# install RVM
echo installing RVM
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source /home/vagrant/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
# install Ruby and make 2.3.1 the default
echo installing ruby
rvm install 2.3.1
rvm use 2.3.1 --default
# install Bundler and Rails
echo installing bundler and rails
gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem install rails -v 4.2.7 --no-ri --no-rdoc
# install postgres and its dependencies
echo installing psql and its dependencies
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev


#VAGRANTFILE
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000, host_ip: "127.0.0.1"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh", privileged: false
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048"]  
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]  
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `which ruby` say?

Comment: This is a path problem. Check that you're using the correct `rvm` environment. `gem env` can also help.

Comment: It's worth noting that Vagrant's pretty antiquated by today's standards where Docker has largely supplanted that use case. There's ready-to-roll Rails containers on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com) that might be easier to get going with.